# Passing arguments to selector that is an argument

Tags: ios, objective-c, selector

I have the following method

```
-(void)changeLevelWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)timeInterval withLevel:(NSUInteger)level{

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:timeInterval
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(changeLevel:)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:NO];
}
```

and I want to call the changeLevel:(NSUInteger)level method with the level argument of the method above.

I have tried to put

```
[self performSelector:@selector(changeLevel:) withObject:level]
```

and tried to pass this as an argument but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

`performSelector:withObject:` takes a pointer object (aka an `id`) as an argument, so there is no way to pass in an `NSUInteger` as an argument, as `NSUInteger` is just a typedeffed `unsigned int`. One particular workaround is to encapsulate the level in an `NSNumber` object, and get the `intValue` of the `NSNumber` in the `changeLevel:` method.

It may go as:

```
NSNumber *levelNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)level];
[self performSelector:@selector(changeLevel:) withObject:levelNumber];
```

And change the signature and implementation of `changeLevel:` as follows:

```
-(void)changeLevel:(NSNumber*)levelNumber{
    int level = [levelNumber intValue];
    //do anything you want with the level..
}
```

For firing the method after an interval, you can try:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(changeLevel:) withObject:levelNumber afterDelay:timeInterval];
```

Instead of scheduling a timer directly.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the following method instead of the method above to make everything work correctly.

```
-(void)changeLevelWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)timeInterval withLevel:(NSUInteger)level{

NSNumber *levelNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)level];

[self performSelector:@selector(changeLevel:) withObject:levelNumber afterDelay:timeInterval];
}
```